# What is a weakly first order phase transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, phase-diagram

I found some articles talking about a weakly first order phase transition; for example this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.15462

I don't get what it is and find no clear sources on the phenomena. So, what is it?

Comment: I am not a specialist, so I'll let somebody else answer, but a very rough and superficial characterization would be that a weakly first-order phase transition is a first-order phase transition in which the correlation length becomes very large (but, of course, stays finite) and the "jumps" of the discontinuous observables are very small. It is often very hard to distinguish between these transitions and second-order ones. A standard example is the planar 5-state Potts model (for which, numerically, it is indeed very hard to see that the transition is first order).

Comment: By the way, I have just learned a couple of days ago, at a conference I was attending, that there are proposals that the (weakly first order) phase transition in models such as the planar $5$-state Potts model might be describable by a CFT with complex central charge. One paper discussing the latter topic is [this one](https://scipost.org/10.21468/SciPostPhys.5.5.050).